# I can't unverify the new owner on Google Search Console

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I received a notification about a new owner into search Console. I have tried to un-verify the new owner who has been verified via meta tags.
I have cleaned the website, but I can still see the meta tag, but I can't find it looking at the source code of the page.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What meta tag? I don't think this is a Drupal issue.

Comment: Google meta tag doesn't seem to be there. Are you sure the notification was about that site? Maybe it's about some other site? Can you see your site in Google Search Console or Webamster tools? Do you have any Google verification modules installed, such as Metatag Verification or some other? Although it does seem your problem isn't within Drupal but in Google account.

Comment: Guys i can see this meta tag using google Search Console <meta name="google-site-verification" content="qDytNhZ36H1AB5Xcufi--mOmAL-PDyyqrb5QHOwYWf0" />

Comment: @leymannx I have uninstalled Google Analytic Module;   and Meta tag Module... But the issue still persists.

Comment: Just search your code base for `google-site-verification`. Maybe it's in the html.tpl.php of your theme. Maybe you find a module that does it. Who knows. There are probably one hundred different ways how a tag can be added to your theme. But we can't go through every possible one of them. You need to debug this yourself.

Comment: @leymannx Will try to scan the files

Answer (score 1):

I checked all my files; then I found some weird code on includes/boostrap.inc which apparently was setting the meta tag to verify the owner. After I removed that code, I was able to un-verify that owner.

Comment: Uh. Looks like you have been compromised.

Comment: Yes @kevin :-( :-(